# Using SCP/SSH in Ruby with a pem file in an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, scp

Trying to transfer or run commands remotely from an Amazon EC2(Ubuntu) instance with a Ruby script.
I am not able to figure out from the ruby doc for ssh and scp how the .pem file can be passed for authentication

```
# download a file from a remote server
Net::SCP.download!("remote.host.com", "username",
"/remote/path", "/local/path",
:password => password)
```

I have also tried using command line but the issue here is the host is dynamic and I would have to authenticate 'yes' everytime

```
`/usr/bin/scp -i keyfile.pem -r username@some.random.ip:/remote/path /local/path`

The authenticity of host 'some.random.ip (some.random.ip)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is some:random:fingerprint.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Is there any way other than by not disabling SSH host key checking with the command line code. Or is there an option in the net-scp or the net-ssh gem for ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby solution which I did not find in any of their docs

```
Net::SSH.start( hostname, username, :keys => "/path/to/keyfile.pem" ) do|ssh|
    #process
end
```

Answer (score 2):

try a command like this

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i keyfile.pem -r username@some.random.ip
```

You can also add the following line to your ~/.ssh/config file, to avoid using -o commandline switch

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Note: you should probably replace * with the domain name pattern of the remote servers you access

The same should also work with `scp`

Answer (score 0):

To add to what naveed stated, if you want to specify a PEM file for `Net::SCP.upload!` command for example use the `:ssh` hash key to specify the `:keys` hash key value:

```
Net::SCP.upload!("remote.host.com", "username",
  "/local/path", "/remote/path", :ssh => { :keys => "/path/to/keyfile.pem" }) do |ch, name, sent, total|
  ...
end
```

I figured it out from naveed's example and from looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp).